# R: How to get character instead of levels?

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this (I know that the structure is a bit messy, but I need it as the input data (Excel) has three levels of columns):

```
                        NA                     NA.1                     NA.2                     NA.3
1 United States of America United States of America United States of America United States of America
2                  Alabama                  Arizona                 Arkansas               California
3                     <NA>                     <NA>                     <NA>                     <NA>
4                     1225                      399                     1547                      726


df <-    structure(list(`258` = structure(c(3L, 2L, NA, 1L), .Label = c("1225", 
    "Alabama", "United States of America"), class = "factor"), `285` = structure(c(3L, 
    2L, NA, 1L), .Label = c("399", "Arizona", "United States of America"
    ), class = "factor"), `279` = structure(c(3L, 2L, NA, 1L), .Label = c("1547", 
    "Arkansas", "United States of America"), class = "factor"), `340` = structure(c(3L, 
    2L, NA, 1L), .Label = c("726", "California", "United States of America"
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("258", "285", "279", "340"), row.names = c(NA, 
    4L), class = "data.frame")
```

And I want to assign row 2 as column names using:

```
colnames(df) <- df[2,]
```

However, I only get the levels and not the character showing the states. The other way around would be easy. However, I stuck on this for a while without finding a solution. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: `colnames(df) <- unlist(df[2,])`

Comment: `df[2, ]` is a `list` of length 4 but `colnames<-` requires a `character vector of non-zero length equal to the appropriate dimension`

Comment: Your best option, IMO, is to use the `stringsAsFactor = FALSE` when importing the data from excel. This option implies that your data will not be coerced to be a factor, but will be a character instead.